# How to send parameter to _init_

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to send parameter to `_init_` method and  dont know how.

I try to use it like any other function:

```
Library     Functions.client_server.client      WITH NAME    cls 

cls.Start              1.1.1.1
```

In the above example i pass `1.1.1.1` to my Start `function` and i want to be able to pass argument to the `_init_ method`..

In the above example i pass `1.1.1.1` to my Start `function` and i want to be able to pass argument to the `_init_ method`..

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

To path arguments to library place them just after library name before `WITH NAME`:

```
Library     Functions.client_server.client    1.1.1.1    WITH NAME    cls
```

[see details in the RobotFramework: Providing Arguments to Test Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#providing-arguments-to-test-libraries)